# What would be an idiomatic way for avoiding these nested while loops?

Tags: rust, nested

I'm creating a helper function that I will later call to loop through a vector of floats, supposably these are snapshots of the value of a particular commodity in the market over time. However there are sets of zeros in my information i.e. instance where the price was not captured. `twin_bound_zeros()` is supposed to return the first instance of a special case, that is a bunch of zeros bounded by matching prices.

This code below runs successfully as far as I can tell, but is there a more idiomatic way I could write it?

```rust
fn twin_bound_zeros(fl: &[f64], mut i: usize) -> Option<(usize, usize, f64)> {
    let mut l: usize;
    let mut r: usize;
    let len = fl.len();

    // handle for access out of bounds and empty arrays
    if let None = fl.get(i) {
        return None;
    }

    //skip past zero headers
    while fl[i] == 0.0 && i < len {
        i += 1;
    }

    // find first zero and proceeding non-zero return bounding data.
    while i < len {
        'a: while i < len {
            if fl[i] == 0.0 {
                l = i;
                while i < len {
                    if fl[i] != 0.0 {
                        r = i;
                        if fl[l - 1] == fl[r] {
                            return Some((l, r, fl[r]));
                        } else {
                            break 'a;
                        }
                    }
                    i += 1;
                }
            }
            i += 1;
        }
    }
    None
}
```

e.g. here's a test case I wrote for it so it to see that it works

```rust
#[test]
fn works_for_nonzero_headed_arrays() {
    let float_list = [2.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0];
    assert_eq!(twin_bound_zeros(&float_list, 0), Some((3, 4, 1.0)));
}
```

Comment: Since this is working code, this question would be better asked on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Before posting on Code Review please read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users/5778#5778) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Comment: at least explain what is doing this code that look like magic so far

Comment: Fair point thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

With a different approach, we need only one while loop:

```
fn twin_bound_zeros(fl: &[f64]) -> Option<(usize, usize, f64)> {
    let mut hit = None;
    let mut l;
    let mut r = 0;
    while let Some(pos) = fl[r..].iter().position(|&f| f != 0.0) {
        l = r;
        r += pos;
        if let Some(f) = hit {
            if f == fl[r] && l < r {
                return Some((l, r, f));
            }
        }
        hit = Some(fl[r]);
        r += 1;
    }
    None
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=4444c8670f8d92a502b2ab691e90814c)

Comment: thankyou @kaplan for your response, unfortunately in my question there could more than 1 zero i.e. 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1 for example

Comment: So it's going to be a bit more bulky, but only one `while` loop is needed.